# Spark Kafka streaming in spark 2.3.0 with python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I recently upgraded to Spark 2.3.0. I had a existing spark job which used to run on spark 2.2.0.
I am facing the Java Exception of  AbstractMethodError

My simple code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext                                                                                  
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext                                                                    
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils                                                                                                                                                                                       

 if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                        
     print "Here it is!"                                                                                               
     sc = SparkContext(appName="Tester")                                                                           
     ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
```

This is working fine with Spark 2.2.0

With Spark spark 2.3.0, I am getting the following exception:

```
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1) 
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/context.py", line 61, in __init__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/context.py", line 65, in _initialize_context
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1428, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.
: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus$class.$init$(ListenerBus.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.StreamingListenerBus.<init>(StreamingListenerBus.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler.<init>(JobScheduler.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.<init>(JavaStreamingContext.scala:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using  `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11-2.3.0.jar` for spark-submit command with —packages options.
I tried using `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.3.0.jar` along with the --package and --jars options.

```
Python version: 2.7.5
```

I followed guide here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html

spark streaming kafka version 0-8 is deprecated in 2.3.0 but it is still there as per documentation.

My command looks like:

```
spark-submit --master spark://10.183.0.41:7077 --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.3.0  Kafka_test.py
```

For sure, there something changed in scala-underlying code of Spark.

Does anyone have faced the same issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to stream the kafka stream when upgraded the spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824845/unable-to-stream-the-kafka-stream-when-upgraded-the-spark)

Answer (score 1):

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/streaming-kafka-integration.html

support for kafka 0.8 is deprecated at spark2.3.0